# Parent DIv can't scroll because of Position:Fixed content

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, fixed

I made a mobile web page using IScroll.

The composition of the web page is as follows.

> HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="content">

  <div class="a">
    TOP
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="disable">
      Google Ads
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    BOTTOM
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

> CSS

```
html, body, .wrap {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.wrap {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:white;
}


.disable {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:aqua;
  z-index:1;
}
.a, .b {
  width: 100%;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;

  z-index:2;
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
}

.item {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

If you run the code above,

You can scroll by raising the cursor to A and B.

On mobile, you can scroll using touch.

**But, So if you raise your cursor over a DIV with Aqua background color and scroll,**

**I can't scroll.**

The DIV, "Position:Fixed," is...

Since the height is 100%, I don't think there's a scroll event.

**For your information, Item needs a Click event.**

**So the "Pointer-Events: None" property is not allowed.**

The "Trigger" function can't even give you an event.

Give me an idea.

https://jsfiddle.net/kasthe/b3w2hpn1/3/

Comment: Sorry, I will study English hard, the grammar may not be correct using a translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `pointer-events: none` to just the `class=disable` div.  `div class=item` is still clickable.

```js
$(".wrap").css("height", $(document).height() + "px");
console.log($(".wrap").height())
```

```css
html, body, .wrap {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.wrap {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:white;
}


.disable {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:aqua;
  z-index:1;
}
.a, .b {
  width: 100%;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  
  z-index:2;
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
}

.item {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="content">
 
  <div class="a">
    TOP
  </div>
  <div class="item" onclick="alert('item clicked')">
    <div class="disable" style="pointer-events:none">
      Google Ads
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    BOTTOM
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have enough explanation. The content of "disable" is Google Ads, so I can't define the Click event as I want.

Comment: The content of "Disable" is Google Adds, and IFRAM will be included.